# Using didReceiveUserInfo in Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, watchkit, watchos-2

I know according to Apple Docs that `didRecieveUserInfo` doesn't get called immediately when running on the Watch. It might take a few minutes or more to ever get called in the background.

So how can you test this in the Simulator (without having to  sit and wait there for X minutes after you run the Watch app)?

My app is set up to use `didReceiveUserInfo`, and it works off and on, but there is nothing predictable when it will run, so it makes testing and debugging very frustrating. Has anyone else run into this, or are able to shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely be dependent on how your phone app sends data to the watch, but have you tried launching the phone app in the iPhone simulator after your watch app starts up?

In the app I'm working on, my iPhone app sends some data to the watch shortly after it launches. If I begin debugging my watch app from Xcode, after the watch app launches, I then switch over to the iPhone simulator, and manually start my iOS app. Soon after, the `didReceiveUserInfo` methods are called back in the watch app.

Comment: Usually what I do is run the iPhone app and then run the Watch app about 10-15 seconds later. Is what you're saying you do: run iPhone app -> run Watch app -> run iPhone app again? Thanks for the answer and looking forward to the follow up so I can try that if it is what you do.

Comment: I launch the watch app from Xcode. Once it's up and running, I then run the iPhone app. (Not from Xcode, but by clicking the icon in the iPhone simulator.) This allows the debugger to stay attached to the watch app while I'm testing.

Xcode, build & run Watch app -> launch iPhone app in simulator

When the phone app launches, it sends the data, and the watch app's `didReceiveUserInfo` methods are called.

Comment: Ahh got it, that makes perfect sense to be able to have it stay attached to the watch app yet still kick off the iPhone process for it.  Thanks!